# New to MEAN stack. Is there a function I am missing?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, mean-stack

I am needing to sign up new users and I am not getting the success or failure redirect to work. It stays on same signup page and displays GET error 500.

What is wrong with my redirect?
I cant figure out why Im getting a GET error auth/success 500.

my authenticate.js:

```
$scope.signup = function() {
  $http.post('/auth/signup', $scope.user).success(function(data) {
    if (data.state === success) {
      $rootScope.authenticated = true;
      $rootScope.current_user = data.user.username;
      $location.path('/');
    } else {
      $scope.error_message = data.message;
    }
  });
};
```

My redirect code:

```
//sends successful login state back to angular
router.get('auth/success', function(req, res) {
  res.send({state: 'success', user : req.user ? req.user : null});
});

//signup
router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
  successRedirect: '/auth/success',
  failureRedirect: '/auth/failure'
}));
```

Comment: from AngularJs you are calling `/auth/signup` but in your server your route is `/signup`, could be this the issue?